# ArcMap KML Displaying Red X for Point Symbology in Google Earth

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, kml, google-earth

I used the "layer to kml" tool on a point layer that I had symbolized with standard symbols in ArcMap 10.4.1. I then brought the KML into Google Earth and some of the point symbols are red X's. I tried using ArcGIS Pro also, and it still does it. There is nothing particular about these points that are each plotted with Lat and Long and each try I do it with, the symbol that is exhibiting the red X changes to a different one.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I have searched everywhere.

Comment: export to .kmz (it will carry the icon). doc.kml will reference to symbol/icon correctly https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives